# Can Sitecore Social Connector Module get tweets with a partcular #tag?

Tags: twitter, sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-social-connected

We need to count tweets with a particular hashtag in a website developed with Sitecore,so I was curious to know can we utilize the Social Connector Module to accomplish our requirement.

Basically we want a schedule task which will query Twitter API in every 5 minute to get all tweets with #tag.

-Regards,
Vikram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So ended up using [TweetInvi](https://tweetinvi.codeplex.com/),greate library.